# Kendo Dropdownlist is hidden behind PDFViewer in Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on one `MVC` project with using `Kendo DropDwonList`.

The issue is shown in below figure.

[image]

The Kendo DropDownList items are hidden behind PDFViewer.
This happened only in safari browser.
When i use normal HTML dropdownlist control, it works fine.

Comment: Can you put up some sample code that behaves the same?

Comment: Css's z index property specifies the "stacking" order of elements

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a CSS clearfix element in between the two controls.  If you're not familiar with that, it would look something like this: http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix